# Append query not working Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am building a dentist appointment booking system for uni.  I have built the whole thing and until yesterday it was working fine.

I have an append query that i would like to append the Operation_ID, Treatment_ID and Patient_ID from tblOperation_Schedule where Op_Complete = 1 and the Operation_ID doesn't already exist in the invoice table.

For some reason, the rows are not appending but i cannot spot the problem.  I have been looking at it trying to think of another way it should be written but i am by no means an expert and connect see the problem.  Query below.

```
INSERT INTO tblInvoices 
( Treatment_ID, Operation_ID, Patient_ID )

SELECT 
tblOperation_Schedule.Treatment_ID, 
tblOperation_Schedule.Operation_ID, 
tblOperation_Schedule.Patient_ID

FROM tblOperation_Schedule 
INNER JOIN tblInvoices ON 
tblOperation_Schedule.Operation_ID = tblInvoices.Operation_ID
WHERE 
(((tblOperation_Schedule.Operation_ID) Not In (Select [Operation_ID] 
from tblInvoices)) 
AND 
(((tblOperation_Schedule.Op_Complete)="1"));
```

Is anyone able to spot a problem with this or suggest another reason why this might not be working please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you make an `INNER JOIN` of two tables using `Operation_ID`, then in `WHERE`, you check `tblOperation_Schedule.Operation_ID` NOT IN ANY `Operation_ID` FROM `tblInvoices`. So your `WHERE` condition conflict with your `JOIN` condition, and it make no row in return.

At least you should change your query to this:

```
INSERT INTO tblInvoices 
    ( Treatment_ID, Operation_ID, Patient_ID )
SELECT Treatment_ID, 
    Operation_ID, 
    Patient_ID
FROM tblOperation_Schedule 
WHERE
    Operation_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT [Operation_ID] 
        FROM tblInvoices
    )
    AND Op_Complete = "1";
```

Comment: Eureka!!! I cant believe thats what it was.  It makes sense of course and its a lesson well learned!  I spent ages staring at it trying to figure our what was wrong.  Maybe that the issue.  Staring too long!  Thanks a bunch Pham

Comment: Note that `NOT EXISTS` is often preferred over `NOT IN` with subqueries, because it often has better performance (it gets optimized to an `ANTI JOIN` instead of querying a list and comparing to that list for every row), and because `NOT IN` will fail if the table contains any null values.